# Ajuda no evento focus, não quer funcionar

Tags: javascript, jquery

O Evento focus do textbox não funciona, o valor x está correto, mas componente não altera seu valor, alguma dica, por favor.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtSchool').textbox('textbox').bind('keypress focus blur', function (e) {
            CallEvents($(this), e);})
    });

    function CallEvents(Sender, e) {            
        if (e.type == 'focus') {
            var rd = $(Sender).prop('readonly');
            var rd = false; //testing...
            if (!rd) {
                var q = String($(Sender).val());
                var x = q.replace(/\./g, "a");   //replacing dot by a
                //$.messager.alert('SCObraNet', 'focus ' + x, 'info');
                $(Sender).val(x);   //não preenche o campo solicitado com o conteúdo x
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (e.type == 'keypress') {
            //$.messager.alert('SCObraNet', 'keypress ', 'info');
        }
        else if (e.type == 'blur') {
            //$.messager.alert('SCObraNet', 'blur', 'info');
        }
    };
</script>
```

---

Testei de outras maneiras e nada, por exemplo

```
    $('#txt').textbox('textbox').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).val("00000");         //don't set
    });

    or

    $('#txt').textbox('textbox').bind('focus', function () {
        $(this).val("00000");         //don't set
    });

    or

    $('#txt').textbox('textbox').bind('focusin', function () {
        $(this).val("00000");         //don't set
    });
```

Comment: Tens caracteres dentro dos argumentos aqui `CallEvents($(this), e);})`... muda para `CallEvents(this, e)`

Answer (score 1):

A função `CallEvents` aceita dois argumentos. O `this` e o *evento*. Estás a passar "lixo" para a função como `;` e um `)` a mais. Não precisas passar `$(this)` pois o CallEvents já faz `$(Sender)`, assim basta:

```
CallEvents(this, e);
```

Podias também mudar essa função CallEvents para :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtSchool').textbox('textbox').bind('keypress focus blur', CallEvents);
});

function CallEvents(e) { 
    var Sender = $(this);           
    if (e.type == 'focus') {
        var rd = Sender.prop('readonly');
        var rd = false; //testing...
        if (!rd) {
            var q = String(Sender.val());
            var x = q.replace(/\./g, "a");   //replacing dot by a
            //$.messager.alert('SCObraNet', 'focus ' + x, 'info');
            Sender.val(x);   //não preenche o campo solicitado com o conteúdo x
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (e.type == 'keypress') {
        //$.messager.alert('SCObraNet', 'keypress ', 'info');
    }
    else if (e.type == 'blur') {
        //$.messager.alert('SCObraNet', 'blur', 'info');
    }
};
```

Comment: Olá Sérgio. Como estou a usar easyui-textbox é necessário passar à função como argumento sim, fiz o teste conforme sugeristes e não funcionou. Mas o problema maior é que não consigo alterar o valor tanto no focus, focusin, focusout ou blur, nenhum desses eventos obtenho sucesso.

Comment: @Cannon777 porque usas `$('#txt').textbox('textbox')`? isso é um plugin `.textbox()`? tens um link para o plugin?

Comment: estou a usar o framework da EasyUI, segue o link: [link] (http://www.jeasyui.com/) muito bom por sinal. Consegui resolver por outros caminhos. Muito grato por comentar.